# Making an automatic log table yearly

Tags: tables

I did a quick doodle in Excel and I like to make a table that looks like the below.  Essentially the issue is, I want it to take up the entire page, half the month on one column, and the other half on the next column, with the daily waste weight log like so, and i like for it to be automatically generated so i have 12 pages when outputted, where each month is on a page, since it is being handfilled out for the weight and initials, i need some spacing so the width and height of the columns should be spread out enough for it to fit but without enlarging the font sizes.

I think I can do this without the dates but the dates is crucial and I really cannot figure out how to do this so the output of the dates is actually correct for each month.

[image: Log file]

Code isn't much since I have no idea what I am doing.  I am more used to doing scientific chemistry papers which I am pretty decent at now.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}
% loop this
%\section*{January 2016}  % this should be generated automatically
\newcounter{month}
\forloop{month}{1}{\value{month} <= 12}{
\section*{month} % how do i print the word the number represents in English?
\begin{table}[h]   % one table per page/ dates should be in two columns     split in half
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Daily Waste Weight Log} \\ \hline
            \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Weight} & \textbf{Initials} &     \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Weight} & \textbf{Initals} \\ \hline
                dynamic  & --- & space for filling & dynamic & ---  & --- \\     \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        \pagebreak
    }
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Has this something to do with TeX and friends? If it has, please add the code you have so far.

Comment: Yes it is TeX.  I started this at work and forgot to paste the code.  Oops.  I will edit the post above with what I got so far (shortly).  Sorry about that.

Comment: The `pgfcalendar` package (provided with [`pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)) might help with automation. It's described in the `pgf` manual, but I've also got [a chapter](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/calendars.shtml) in one of my books that describes it, including the [looping macro `\pgfcalendar`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/displaycalendar.shtml).